# std::move does not move for rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I am new to move semantics.

When I run the following code:

```
std::string h{"move"};
auto r = std::move(h);
std::cout << h << std::endl;
std::cout << r << std::endl;
```

I get the expected result:

```
{empty line} 
move
```

However when I run this:

```
std::string h{"move"};
auto&& r = std::move(h);
std::cout << h << std::endl;
std::cout << r << std::endl;
```

While I expected the same output as above, I get the output:

```
move
move
```

Why was not the move constructor called in this case and the value was set to some unspecified value?

Comment: `r` is a reference, that means it refers to `h`.  There is only one object in this example,  where do you imagine moving happen?

Answer (score 3):

`std::move` by itself does nothing but cast its argument to `T &&`.

It's due to the fact that you assign the `std::string &&` to `r` in the first example that `h`'s data is moved.

In the second case, you're assigning an `std::string &&` to an `std::string &&`, i.e. a reference. Whether it's an lvalue or rvalue reference doesn't really matter here. The fact is that no `std::string` object needs to be created, hence `h`'s data is not moved.

Comment: I always find so counterintuitive that `std::move` does not actually move anything, it's just the cast you are talking about, and the actual move happens somewhere else, when assigning a T&& to a T.
Bad naming choice by the c++ standard guys IMHO